# UITableView cells do not respond to input after resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am adding new rows in my table view and resizing it according to its contents, but after the resize, the cell contents, like a button and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` are not being invoked.

Here is the resizing code:

```
CGRect frame = cell.replayTableView.frame; 
int height = (model.replyComments.count*61)+3; 
frame.size = CGSizeMake(cell.replayTableView.frame.size.width, height); 
cell.tableviewReplay.refTable.frame=frame;
```

Comment: Are you using Autolayout? If yes then Frame property does not work as intended. You need to update Autolayout constraint of UItableview.

Answer (score 2):

Assign a height on heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (indexPath.Row == 1)
     return 50.0;
  else if (indexPath.Row == 2)
     return 60;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you are using auto layouts you have to update constraints also .
In your code you are getting frame from a different view

```
CGRect frame = cell.replayTableView.frame;
```

after changing height

```
CGRect frame = cell.replayTableView.frame; 
int height = (model.replyComments.count*61)+3; 
frame.size = CGSizeMake(cell.replayTableView.frame.size.width, height);
```

but then setting it to different view

```
cell.tableviewReplay.refTable.frame=frame;
```

This may be creating issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Declare a variable in yourController.h   CGFloat tableHeight;

// set height in heightforRowAtindex
// run loop for number of rows in ur tableview data array
// put this code when ur data array is not empty  i.e after responce of webservice etc

// as your tableview is and custom cells are not created programatically , so you need viewDidLayoutSubviews to reset frames 
tableHeight = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < [dataArray count]; i ++) {
            tableHeight += [self tableView:self.multipleArticletableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        }
 [self viewDidLayoutSubviews];
// put code below in viewDidLayoutSubviews method . it will work
        self.multipleArticletableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.multipleArticletableView.frame.origin.x, self.multipleArticletableView.frame.origin.y,self.multipleArticletableView.frame.size.width, tableHeight);
```

Comment: ur tableview is programatic or u have drag and drop to interface

Answer (score 0):

Most common cause for this kind of issues are cells having some UI components that intercepts the user tap and do not pass on the tap to underneath cell. You can fix this by disabling  user interaction on those components.

For example if you had added a `UIView` in your cell then call

```
otherView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```